# Jsoup: Get text after any closed tag

Tags: java, jsoup

i am trying to get text after closed tag but not able to find any good solution my html is like this :

```
<h2>Some Header</h2>
I want to get this
```

and yes remember it doesn't have any container just this.

any solutions?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to select the H2 element, and then get the text node by following the H2's [next sibling](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#nextSibling--). (In the DOM tree, the H2 and the text you're after are siblings under the body element.)

This code works:

```
String html = "<h2>Some Header</h2>\nI want to get this";
Element h2 = Jsoup.parse(html).select("h2").first();
Node text = h2.nextSibling();

System.out.println(text.toString());
```

And outputs:

`I want to get this`

Comment: this will fetch only data from very first h2 tag and what about second h2 tag if it is there?

Comment: `.select()` returns [Elements](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) so you can iterate on the head `h2` matches, and call `nextSibling()` on those. (I.e. don't hit `first()` but iterate.)